# Solr edismax with multiple function queries and boosting query in a request

Tags: solr4

I am looking for a way to introduce boosts on Popularity (integer value) and recency (Year, YYYY format) under EDisMax handler ang getting confused with bq, bf, boost and !boost syntax.

Also, on using !boost syntax, df field becomes mandatory and restricts me to search on qf fields configured in solrconfig.xml.

The cookbook4, too doesn't offer any help on this, and I purchased it for no worth :(

Can you please help me on this ?

Thanx,
Manu